# Postgresql extraction between two DateTime but ingnore only seconds

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Postgresql extraction between two DateTime but ignore only seconds (seconds for two datetime = 00)

```
06.09.2014 18:54:35   -  06.09.2014 18:54:35
DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI    -  DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI
```

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (occ.execute_finishtime-occ.execute_starttime)::interval) /60)::INTEGER

Comment: (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (finishtime - starttime)::interval) /60)::INTEGER

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I think your question needs editing as I don't understand what's your exact question...

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like you're looking for the date_trunc() function.

```
with test_data as (
  select timestamp '2015-01-01 08:00:13' as ts union all
  select timestamp '2015-01-01 08:13:27'       union all
  select timestamp '2015-01-01 09:00:27'       union all
  select timestamp '2015-01-01 09:01:42' 
)
select *, date_trunc('minute', ts) 
from test_data
where date_trunc('minute', ts) between '2015-01-01 08:00' and '2015-01-01 09:00';
```

```
ts                    date_trunc
--
2015-01-01 08:00:13   2015-01-01 08:00:00
2015-01-01 08:13:27   2015-01-01 08:13:00
2015-01-01 09:00:27   2015-01-01 09:00:00
```

If you need this kind of query to use an index, you'll need to create an index on the expression `date_trunc('minute', your_column_name)`.

Comment: Just a side note: you don't need the `select ... union ..` thing in Postgres. Just use a `values (...)` clause.